# javascript addEventListener firing on all elements

Tags: javascript, validation, addeventlistener, attachevent

Im sure I have missed something obvious but any idea why the following addEventListener code is firing everywhere (on not just on the submit button)?

HTML:

```
    <form action="#">
        <input type="text"><br>
        <input type="text"><br>
        <button id="submit">submit</button><br>
    </form>
```

JS:

```
    function validate () {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var inputs_length = inputs.length-1;
        for (i=0; i<=inputs_length; i++) {
            var inputs_value = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].value;
            if (inputs_value == "") {
                alert('there is a text box empty');
            }
        }

    }   

    var el = document.getElementById('submit');

    if (el.addEventListener) {  
        el = addEventListener('click', validate, false);   
    } else if (el.attachEvent)  {  
      el.attachEvent('onclick', validate);  
    }
```

THE FIX IS CHANGE

```
el = addEventListener('click', validate, false);
```

TO

```
el.addEventListener('click', validate, false);
```

MY TYPO :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
if (el.addEventListener) {  
    el = addEventListener('click', validate, false);
```

To this:

```
if (el.addEventListener) {  
    el.addEventListener('click', validate, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

A lengthy comment.

In your code:

```
    // inputs is an HTMLCollection of all the inputs
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    // No need for the -1
    var inputs_length = inputs.length;

    // Don't forget to declare counters too, very important
    // Just use < length
    for (var i=0; i<inputs_length; i++) {

        // Instead of this very inefficient method
        var inputs_value = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].value;

        // use the collection you already have
        var inputs_value = inputs[i].value;

        if (inputs_value == "") {
            alert('there is a text box empty');
        }
    }
```

Also better to declare `inputs_value` at the beginning so all declarations are in one place, but as you have it is not harmful.

Oh, and don't give a form element a name or id of "submit" (or any other form method) as it will shadow the form method of the same name so it can't be called.

Comment: Cool. Cheers for the tips RobG